# Are all Phoenix connectors (of the same size) cross compatible?

Tags: connector

I always seem to be losing phoenix connectors.

I want to buy a bag of them to keep in the office as spares.

Are all phoenix connectors of the same size cross compatible ? Eg. could the same phoenix connector be used on a Lutron keypad, a multi zone audio amp ? (as long as they fit in the slot).

Or do they have other technical parameters i need to be aware of eg. voltage or other ?

Comment: The Phoenix Contact (note capitals) catalogues and sales support are excellent. Start there.

Comment: I can say from experience that that are not all the same size.

Comment: @Transistor  Phoenix is more a style than a brand name, there are compatible plugs from many different manufacturers.

Comment: @Jasen what are they like? I've only ever seen the word phoenix in reference to the brand phoenix contact (or in reference to the mythical bird, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: @Hearth see photo in my answer, this is the style of pluggable terminal strip that Phoenix Contact seems most famous for.

Comment: If you search 3.81mm pitch in Digikey's "Terminal Blocks - Headers, Plugs and Sockets" you'll find several manufacturers including, TE, OnShore, Molex, Weidmuller, and of-course Phoenix Contact, if you search on LCSC you'll find more still.

Comment: I just call those pluggable terminal blocks. To me, Phoenix connector means about just as much as Molex connector; very little since they're both companies that make a thousand different connectors. I wouldn't assume pluggable terminal blocks are cross compatible. There are many different styles in that plastic molding.

Comment: Look on the side of the original part. There should be identifying info molded into it. Look up the reference, look for the part series name e.g. COMBICON etc. Phoenix is a top shelf brand, costs a little more but super well organized and very reliable. There are cheaper clones with varying quality interchangeabilitly.

Comment: Not really. Also there are many phoenix lookalike but they don't always fit properly. We call them 'euroblocks' as general name since everyone makes them

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There's a metric and a inch size, (3.5mm and 3.81mm pitch) that both look like the above, and also a 5.08mm that looks completely different. there are also variations with the barrels higher or lower on the plug body and versions with the cables at 90 degrees and the screws at 180 degrees and there's many different manufacturers making these connectors.

Plugs from different manufacturers are physically compatible so long as they are the right size.

Some plugs are rated for different maximum currents or voltages or temperature ranges etc if you need the guaranteed performance you should use the genuine connector.

If you have only modest needs like 2A at 24V and room temperature then you'll have no trouble mixing and matching

Comment: ‘Compatible’ but the mated performance can vary. Best to mate same brand with same brand especially if running close to the max specs. I can tell you that they are not all the same.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the pitch:

There are two types of 3.5 mm terminal blocks: a) single cavity header; b) partitioned cavity header.

All others are compatible for a given pitch. For example, all 2.5 mm are compatible, and all 2.54 mm are compatible, but 2.5 mm and 2.54 mm ones look quite different.